# AWS EC2 FTP Permission Denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, ftp

I was able to connect to my AWS EC2 with Filezilla but when I go to move files or delete them I get this error in the log. [Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHkOt.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a permission issue. Use this command.

```
sudo rm var/www/info.php
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably dont have the rights.
Try right click on the file and "Permissions" check the "read", "execute", "write" for this info.php file.
It should work.